# html or body size - padding/height/margin/something

Tags: html, css, height, padding

No mater how much I play around with padding and margin properties I can't seem to solve an issue I have on larger screens - the bottom of the html has a "cut off" where it appears to have a margin from the bottom of the screen. I do not know which element this is but all the elements have been reset to have 0 padding or margin.

When I add the following css I find that the gap really is at the bottom - there are no elements underneath:

```
* {outline: solid 1px;}
```

Here is a url to the site if any kind person would like to take a look: http://preview.tinyurl.com/7ywoqpf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fiddled with firebug and noticed that setting:

html {height: 100%;}

has solved the problem, will update the site later this evening

Answer (score 2):

Your `div.holder` has a `min-height` of 650 pixels.

When I remove that, the gap vanishes for me.

The best thing to do in these cases is a document inspector like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/dom) or Chrome's built in one. They will show you which elements in the DOM take up which space exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that block level elements will fill their container widthways but not in height. So maybe it's the case that divs and containers within your page aren't tall enough to reach the bottom. There's something called a "push divs", "sticky footers" where that div will stay at the bottom. Maybe you'd put your background image within that and it'd stay at the bottom. There are several errors in your css though, and you can't have .5 of a pixel.

Comment: @i-CINICA thanks for info I'll look into "push div" is that an element with particular properties? Also, do let me know any CSS issues I'm a novice

Comment: A "push div", isn't a particular property, it's a group of properties to achieve an effect. A little trickery, almost. It seems what you're after, is that background image staying at the bottom left of the users' screen, but unless your content is exactly the height of their screen, it won't work. A div pushed to the bottom, with a height tall enough to contain that image should work. There's probably simpler ways, but I can't really have other websites on my screen, I'm at work... :( Give "Stylizer" a try, it's a realtime css editor, and will only allow you to write valid CSS.